# How to make optional argument Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the below situation

I have to match something like

```
abc#(x,-12d)

or

abc#(x,-12d, 24d) etc.
```

That means the last parameter is optional.

I have already made the regular expression and it works but since I donot know how to make optional , henceforth I am using two different regExpression.

```
public static bool ValidFn(string input)
        {          
            string regEx1 = @"^[a-zA-Z]*#\([A-Za-z0-9]+,[-|+]?\d+[dwmqy],[-|+]?\d+[dwmqy]\)";
            string regEx2 = @"^[a-zA-Z]*#\([A-Za-z0-9]+,[-|+]?\d+[dwmqy]\)";
            Regex r1 = new Regex(regEx1);
            Regex r2 = new Regex(regEx2);
            Match m1 = r1.Match(input);
            Match m2 = r2.Match(input);
            if (m1.Success || m2.Success) return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

How can I make regExp1 as optional so that I can eliminate the use of regExp2.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `?` character in regex means "Repeat 0 or 1 time". Therefore, it makes a statement optional.

You want to capture the last ", 24d" when it exists. You need to wrap what captures ", 24d" with a ? character.

This regex will do :

```
string regEx1 = @"^[a-zA-Z]*#\([A-Za-z0-9]+,[-|+]?\d+[dwmqy](,\s*[-|+]?\d+[dwmqy])?\)";
```

Note that i've added a `\s*` to capture white spaces after the `,`

Answer (score 0):

Optional parts are marked with `?`, aren't they? You have already used it in `[-|+]?`.